# Export React.JS variable and use in other file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So what I want to do is take the input from the radio buttons (**metric** or **imperial**) from *Forecast.js*, use them in a function in *Conditions.js* to determine whether it's hot or cold. I've exported the variable **unit** from *Forecast.js* but when I try to use it in the **clothes()** function it doesn't work.
I've tried everything I found online and I tried to understand but I'm new to Reactjs.

Conditions.js
https://pastebin.com/RHbLuqZD

```
import { unit } from '../Forecast/Forecast.js';

function clothes(t) {
    if (unit === "metric") {
        if (Number('t') <= 20)
            return (<>
                <img src={Cold} alt="wind icon" style={{ width: 50, marginRight: 20, height: 50 }} />
            It's cold, dress accordingly!
            </>);
        else
            return (<>
                <img src={Hot} alt="wind icon" style={{ width: 50, marginRight: 20, height: 50 }} />
            It's Warm, dress accordingly!
            </>);
    }

    if (unit === "imperial") {
        if (Number('t') <= 70)
            return (<>
                <img src={Cold} alt="wind icon" style={{ width: 50, marginRight: 20, height: 50 }} />
            It's cold, dress accordingly!
            </>);
        else
            return (<>
                <img src={Hot} alt="wind icon" style={{ width: 50, marginRight: 20, height: 50 }} />
            It's Warm, dress accordingly!
            </>);
    }
}
```

Forecast.js
https://pastebin.com/wcBu8bwA

```
export default Forecast;
export let unit = this.state.unit;
```

The reason it doesn't work could be because I didn't do the import and export properly or because I didn't use the imported variable properly.

**Edit:** As I specified I'm a beginner, I don't know a lot, what I want is to see how to solve the problem and then understand how to do it. I just need to understand the problem with my code, or an alternative.

Comment: do you know what `this` exactly is? because it's a global variable inside of a javascript file it is the `window` object `this`  when used outside of a `method`  refer to the `window` object and that `window` object doesn't have any `state` property in it.

Comment: It will never work... You don't have access to the state outside of `Forecast` function

Comment: Ok so how am I supposed to do it? I tried everything online and couldn't make it work.

Comment: This `Number('t')` is not going to work, it will convert a string `"t"` to number. `Number(t)` should be the correct. I would, if I were you, try some better name for this variable, though. Also, you don't need the `else` there, as you are returning after the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

1. if('clothes' and 'Forecast' is a parent-child realationship)

   the 'unit' state, can be deliver by 'props'

```
function Parent(props){
const [unit,setUnit] = useState("")
return(
 <Child unit={unit}>
)
}
   
function Child(props){
  console.log(props.unit)
return(
<div/>
)
}
```

2. else.  you can learn about 'react-redux'

Comment: ... or useContext

Answer (score 1):

This is not how the whole thing works. One state variable like `unit` in one component is not exportable like that.

There are mainly two things you can do:

- one is pass this `unit` value to the `Conditions.js` as a prop and then pass it on to the `clothes` function (when using it, just like you pass the temperature value) to work with it;
- another one is to have a state management tool like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [reactN](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn) or even use the [React's built-in context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). If you have need to use one of those only once it may not compensate the extra boilerplate, but it may be worth learning about them at least.